# CMD - language query task

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I would like to make a batch, which query the OS's language and after it does commands depending the result.

My code is:

```
@echo off 
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0409 GOTO ENGLISH
GOTO GERMANY
:ENGLISH 
echo English
PAUSE
:GERMANY 
echo Germany 
PAUSE
```

I know if the req query result is 0409--> English, 0407--> Germany.
I try with:

```
reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0409 (GOTO ENGLISH) 
else %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0409 (GOTO GERMANY)
```

But didn't work. Can somebody help me?

I don't know if there is a problem with the if function. Or that cmd cannot read the received value.

Comment: Your `if`/`else` syntax is wrong! Type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and learn how it works…

Comment: Please do not check `ControlSet001`, `ControlSet002`, `ControlSet003` `ControlSet004` … etc. You should be using whichever is mapped for the running session, i.e. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet`. Whilst machines which have never had issues may still have the current or most recent session as `ControlSet001`, you should not assume that to be the case. That is the very reason why the appropriate one is mapped to the `CurrentControlSet` subkey in the first place.

Comment: There are close to eight hundred different language ID's in Windows. I'm certain your code does not have that many labels to `GOTO`. Could you therefore try to explain the task with a little more detail, so that it is possible to better assist you with your problem, or advise a more suitable methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, `reg` returns an `%errorlevel%` of zero, if successful or one, if unsuccessful (typo, key or value non-existent).

You need to parse the output with a `for /f` loop to get the desired number:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage') do set "lang=%%a"
if "%lang%" == "0407" goto :German
if "%lang%" == "0409" goto :English
echo There is no label for %lang%
goto :eof
:ENGLISH 
echo English
PAUSE
goto :eof
:GERMANY 
echo Germany 
PAUSE
goto :eof
```

You have to force `if` to compare strings instead of numbers because numbers starting with a zero are treated as octal, which means `0409` is an invalid octal number and will lead to a script-breaking error if treated as a number.

You have to terminate your main code and subroutines with a `goto :eof` to prevent the parser to "fall through" the following subroutine.

Comment: Could you help me to clearly understand ?

I looked up how the for command works, and the /f examines the output. 


[FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command ]

But i'dont know how need I use this command our batch. Could you put my code this command ?

Comment: We are using the variant `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command` here.

Comment: Could you put this my code ?